# multiprocessing.Pool: class instances and pickle error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am trying  to run some script on 10 connected boards (parallel process limit of 4 for stability). I hit the following error and here is the piece of code snippet. I believe it is due to class instance but each object of the class is independent and none of the resources are shared (nor returned)

```
TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
```

Code:

```
def update_device_worker(worker):
    worker.run()

class Worker :
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device

    def run(self):
       << bash code to run on IoT devices to cleanup and restart>>

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=1)
workers = [Worker(d) for d in connected_IoT_Devices]
pool.map(update_device_worker, workers)

class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device
        self.ipaddress,  self.serial, self.model, self.log, 
            = None, None, None, None
        self.log = os.path.join(logPath,self.serial+ ".log")
        custom_logger(self.log)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.log)
        self.logger.info("Logger started for %s ", self.serial)
```

Comment: Looks like one the devices in `connected_IoT_Devices` contains a `Lock` object (you appear to be trying to share those). Since you haven't shown the definition of "device"s, it's at best difficult to suggest a workaround.

Comment: @martineau : Updated

Comment: Your update still doesn't show what the `device` being passed the `Device` class' `__init__()` is. I also suspect that you're going to have a similar problem with the instance's `logger` attribute. Basically you can only pass objects to other processes that can be pickled. Sometimes you can overcome that limitation by using `multiprocessing` `Manager`s. See the `multiprocessing` documentation for details.